# ASP Net core Cors Preflight Requests

Tags: asp.net-core, cors

Есть проблема: не могу общаться с бэкэндом из под расширения для Chrome.
Причиной тому - Cors, но частично я ее уже решил.

Не сосем понятно что делать с `Preflight requests`.
Во всех ответах, связанных с Cors и Asp net core примерно одно и тоже:

```
services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("MyPolicy", builder =>
    {
        builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
               .AllowAnyMethod()
               .AllowAnyHeader();
    }));
```

Но, это не работает для `Preflight requests`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как костыль знаю банальное решение:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("x")]
public IActionResult X()
{
    return new OkObjectResult(some_staff);
}

[HttpPatch]
[Route("x")]
public IActionResult XPatch()
{
    return new OkResult();
}
```

- подвязывать к каждому `Route` банальный `Patch` с возвратом 200.
  Но после 4-ого роута у меня отсохли пальцы и, очевидно, должно быть решение.

Comment: Может `middleware` закинуть свой кастомный? Хотя ну должна была эта проблема уже быть решена

Comment: а вы `UseCors()` используете?

Comment: @ExplodingKitten, нет, мне казалось, что `UseCors()` только `Headers` докидывает. Возможно, я неправ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Метод `AddCors()` добавляет конфигурацию для `CORS`, но больше ничего не делает, т.е. в вашем `DI` появляется объект конфигурации (`CorsOptions`) в котором вы говорите, что вы разрешаете любые origin, header, method. Для того, чтобы у вас начал работать CORS нужно использовать также `UseCors()`, этот метод добавит нужный `middleware` (`CorsMiddleware`), который и будет добавлять правильные заголовки (`Access-Control-Allow-Origin`, `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` ..., их и ожидает увидеть браузер в ответе) и обрабатывать `preflight` запросы.

Т.к. вы используете `policy` не с именем по умолчанию, то вам нужно передавать имя `policy`: `UseCors("MyPolicy")` и его нужно вызывать до `UseRouting()`.

[Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-5.0)